Why's there a duplicate of my array? Javascript
When I use consolelog on my array there are 2 duplicates of it, ones empty and ones with the objects that get pushed, when I refresh the page (I use localStorage to save the array) the array has an exact copy. Here's the code:
let projectArray = [];

const saveProjectArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("projectList"));
projectArray = saveProjectArray;

allTask.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    saveProjectArray.forEach(element => {
        console.log(`Name: ${element.name}`);
    });
});

function Project(name, id){
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
}

function makeProject(projectName){

    const newProjectObj = new Project(projectName, getId);

    //Code
    
    projectArray.push(newProjectObj);

    localStorage.setItem('projectList', JSON.stringify(projectArray));
}

I've tried deleting the localstorage lines but still the issue persists.
UPDATE
The issue was at how I bundled my js scripts in webpack.config.js, I did one entry for every one of them and that would call the script 2 times. I don't know if I was clear but the issue is fixed : ).

It might be useful to include where you log, because you are indeed instantiating an array, then replacing the content of that variable with another array constructed from localstorage.

Not sure how you are calling makeProject().
But one possible case would be to change line 3.
projectArray = [...saveProjectArray];

I am not sure if this will fix the issue but worth trying.
Please let me know if this fixes the issue.

Hey! I'm calling makeproject in another script by exporting it. Adding projectArray = [...saveProjectArray]; didn't fix the problem.
Also this is the full code so there isn't anything confusing https://github.com/Orion-Barjamaj/To-Do-List/blob/main/src/create/project.js

I see projectArray = [saveProjectArray]; on line 11. Please make sure if this is intentional. It's without spread operator

I think I found the issue. There's something wrong with project.js script. It's like it's being called 2 times. I tried adding a new array and consolelog it in project.js and there was 2 arrays, when trying the same thing on index.js it didn't happen. I'll have another look at it, maybe I did something wrong with webpack. I'll tell you when I find the solution.

The issue was at how I bundled my js scripts in webpack.config.js, I did one entry for every one of them and that would call the script 2 times. I don't know if I was clear but the issue is fixed : ).

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
